# How can I cancel the loading of a resource in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, resources

**Synopsis**

Basically I have a web page that loads videos via html5 video tags. I want to be able to stop the loading of a resource in a certain context.

**Context:**

- On my site I have a grid of video thumbnails.
- When you hover over the thumbnail a preview popover of the video (html5) comes up.
- The user manually clicks to play the video preview.
- The previews range from 5-45 seconds.
- The user usually doesn't want to watch the whole preview if it's not what they're looking for.
- So they move their mouse to another video thumbnail and repeat the process.

**Problem:**

Even though the popover disappears when their mouse moves away, the video preview continues to download in the browser, even though this data is no longer necessary and is a drain on the network and the browser.

I would like to save bandwidth and increase browser responsiveness by canceling the download when it's containing div is removed from the dom or set to display:none

Answer (score 0):

```
//cancel image downloads
if(window.stop !== undefined) 
{
  window.stop();
}
else if(document.execCommand !== undefined)
{
  document.execCommand("Stop", false);
}
```

Dont know exactly whether it'll stop the video download but it worked for images